# Do we allow to see the progress during a function call?

Tags: upload, thrift, progress

I am using Thrift to make call to the server. I am trying to send an image. Is there a function allow me to see the progress of the uploading on Thrift.

Answer (score 1):

### Short answer.

No.

### Long answer

To send some large amounts of data, such as an image, you probably already defined a service function like this (or arbitrarily more complex):

```
service FooBar {
    bool SendImageData( 1: binary data) 
}
```

You now transfer the image through that function call. The call does not return until it either succeeds or fails. The Thrift infrastructure does not provide you with a way to get any progress data out of the box. But we do have some options:

1. We could write a special Thrift transport that wraps the original one and provides us with some counters.
2. On the API level, we could change the call to send (especially large) files in chunks, instead of one large block. This way, we have multiple calls and know about the progress we are making.